# Android Linear Layout - How to handle gravity with four rows

Tags: android-layout, imageview, position, android-linearlayout, gravity

I have a linear layout which originally was set to display 9 images in a 3x3 formation. I was using android:layout_gravity="right|top" etc... to correctly position my images (as shown in the XML below).

I needed to add another row, i.e. 3 images across and 4 images down. The new 'bonus' row is causing me a problem in that I can't see how to correctly position the images. With the current settings they overlap the third row.

So, the question is, how can I correctly use a linear layout to position a grid of images that is 3 across and 4 down. I would have thought it possible without needing to use a gridview.

My XML layout code is below.

Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragmentMain">


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/containerMainX"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adViewMain">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTopLeft"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTopCenter"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTopRight"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCenterLeft"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCenterCenter"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCenterRight"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewBottomLeft"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewBottomCenter"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewBottomRight"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewBonusLeft"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewBonusCenter"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewBonusRight"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewGameBackButton"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />


</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out... vertical LinearLayout (weightsum of 4) containing 3 horizontal LinearLayouts each handling their own weighting and, no gravity for the imageViews....

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTopLeft"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTopCenter"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTopRight"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCenterLeft"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCenterCenter"
        android:padding="6dip"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCenterRight"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBottomLeft"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBottomCenter"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBottomRight"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBonusLeft"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBonusCenter"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBonusRight"
        android:padding="6dip"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```